# How to avoid "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection" error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a doubt concerning the Entity Framework in .NET.

I have a simple ASP .NET web page that has to insert some data in SQL Server with this function:

```
public void InsertSimulation()
{
    icarus_portalEntities entitites = new icarus_portalEntities();

    // Build the Simulation
    T004_SIMULATIONS tSimulation = T004_SIMULATIONS.CreateT004_SIMULATIONS(0, name_, creationDate_, gsoapPort_, endTimeStep_, scenarioX_, scenarioY_, penetrationRates_.wifi, penetrationRates_.gprs, penetrationRates_.wimax, penetrationRates_.lte, penetrationRates_.mcn, penetrationRates_.edge, penetrationRates_.hsdpa, totalNumberOfNodes_, "RandomWalkMobility", ((RandomWalkMobility)mobility_).vehicularSpeed, ((RandomWalkMobility)mobility_).angleVariation, ((RandomWalkMobility)mobility_).cellRadius, ((RandomWalkMobility)mobility_).decorrelation, ((RandomWalkMobility)mobility_).minimumDistance, false);

    // Bind the Simulation with the FK of user
    T001_USERS tUser = entitites.T001_USERS.First(p => p.user_name == createdBy_);
    tUser.T004_SIMULATIONS.Add(tSimulation);

    // Bind the Simulation with the FK of the crmm
    T003_CRRM tCrmm = entitites.T003_CRRM.First(p => p.name == crmm_.Name);
    tCrmm.T004_SIMULATIONS.Add(tSimulation);

    // Add the created sessions to the simulation
    foreach (SimulationSession session in SimulationSession.createdSessions_)
    {
        if (session.GetType() == typeof(WebSession))
        {
            // Build the session and web session
            T008_SESSIONS tWebSession = ((WebSession)session).Insert(entitites);

            // Bind the session to the simulation
            tSimulation.T008_SESSIONS.Add(tWebSession);
        }
    }

    // Add the enanabled technologies to the simulator
    foreach (EnabledTechnologies enabled in enabledTechnologies_)
    {
        // Build the enabled technology
        T005_ENABLED_TECHNOLOGIES tEnabled = T005_ENABLED_TECHNOLOGIES.CreateT005_ENABLED_TECHNOLOGIES(0, enabled.centerX, enabled.centerY, enabled.radius, false);

        // Bind the enabled technolgy with the simulator
        T002_SIMULATORS tSimulator = entitites.T002_SIMULATORS.First(p => p.id == enabled.simulatorId);
        tSimulator.T005_ENABLED_TECHNOLOGIES.Add(tEnabled);

        // Bind the enabled technolgoy with the simulation
        tSimulation.T005_ENABLED_TECHNOLOGIES.Add(tEnabled);
    }

    entitites.SaveChanges();
}
```

The thing is that when the code tries the sentence:

```
// Bind the enabled technolgy with the simulator
T002_SIMULATORS tSimulator = entitites.T002_SIMULATORS.First(p => p.id == enabled.simulatorId);
```

It gives me the error:

**The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.**

I found, with other related questions, that somehow the *connection* of the Entity object (`entities`) is closed when it is passed to the method in the statement:

```
// Build the session and web session
T008_SESSIONS tWebSession = ((WebSession)session).Insert(entitites);
```

The `Insert` function is implemented as:

```
public T008_SESSIONS Insert(icarus_portalEntities entities)
{
    // Create new session object with data
    T008_SESSIONS tSession = T008_SESSIONS.CreateT008_SESSIONS(0, name_, periodicty_, false);
    using (entities)
    {
        // Create new web session object with data
        T010_SESSIONS_WEB tSessionWeb = T010_SESSIONS_WEB.CreateT010_SESSIONS_WEB(0, (int)lambda_, (int)pagesPerSession_, (int)objectsSize_.alpha, (int)objectsSize_.beta, (int)objectsPerWebPage_.alpha, (int)objectsPerWebPage_.beta, (int)timeBetweenPages_.alpha, (int)timeBetweenPages_.beta, (int)timeBetweenObjects_.alpha, (int)timeBetweenObjects_.beta, false);

        // Add to the session the web session (bind FK)
        tSession.T010_SESSIONS_WEB.Add(tSessionWeb);

        // Add session to the rest of the entities
        entities.AddToT008_SESSIONS(tSession);

        // Commit all the data to the database
        entities.SaveChanges();

        //var tempSession = entities.T008_SESSIONS.First(n => n.Equals(tSession.id));
        //tempSession.T010_SESSIONS_WEB.Add(tSessionWeb);
    }
    return tSession;        
}
```

The good news is that the code that `Insert` function encapsulates I can move it to the place which is called. So my question is: **What if there is a place in which I would be forced to call the function? How then I could avoid the error. Passing the parameter as reference (I tried and did not work)**

Thank you very much in advance!

Julen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What if there is a place in which I would be forced to call the
>   function? How then I could avoid the
>   error. Passing the parameter as
>   reference (I tried and did not work)

The problem is in your `Insert()` function you are wrapping `entities` in a `using(){}` statement.

```
using (entities) //calls dispose
{
}
```

When the using finishes it is calling dispose on your entities and closing your connection.

Your context should remain active for the lifetime of our unit of work.  Ideally your `using` statement should be in `InsertSimulation()` as from the code it appears that is your unit of work for you `entitites`.

Comment: Thanks! So true I could not see it!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the method public T008_SESSIONS Insert(icarus_portalEntities entities)

you are passing a reference of your entities object and because it is using a using statement

```
using (entities) {}
```

it will dispose the object